# Is it possible to make a list in crystal report with different tables or category?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

Is it possible to make a list in crystal report with different tables or category? I mean, like this:

Project Title:         Expenses        Amount

Name of Project1            Item1.1             0.00
                                       Item1.2              0.00
                                       Item1.3         0.00

Name of Project2            Item2.1         0.00
                                       Item2.2         0.00

**TOTAL:**                                               **0.00**

Both 'Name of project' and 'Item' comes from different table in a mysql database. The field that connects the two is project_id. Waht it does to me is that it seperates Different projects in different pages. What I want is to display them in one page only. is that possible?

Any suggestions? God bless!

Answer (score 0):

Using the project_id field, frame a query using inner join and you can pull out the data.

Update:

do you have table and data script? It will be easy to answer after viewing the structure

Comment: will it not multiply the name of project? or can i use group by?